# collections.OrderedDict not working on json.dump()

Tags: python, json, dictionary, collections

I am not using this correctly, as it is not yielding the order I want:

```
import json
from collections import OrderedDict

dict_1 = {}
dict_2 = {}

metadata = {
        'id': 1,
        'columns': [dict_1],
        'dtypes': [dict_2],
    }

with open('metadata.json', 'w') as metadata_dumped :
    json.dump(metadata, metadata_dumped, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '), object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
```

I have coded `id` and 2 `dictionaries` in the order I want outputted.

Yet the output file has the last 2 `dictionaries` placed on top of the .json.

Where am I going wrong in my thinking? What would be a *'standard'* solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#basic-usage), `sort_keys` will sort the keys, not preserve order.

> If sort_keys is true (default: False), then the output of dictionaries will be sorted by key.

Comment: Interesting. What implementation do I need to get my desired output then?

Comment: don't use sort_keys